# The property 'Entity1.Entity2' is of type 'Entity2' which is not supported by current database provider

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to create an initial migration with code-first. I have 2 entity classes as follows:

```
public class Entity1
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

And my DbContext as follows;

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity1> Entity1List { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entity2> Entity2List { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Entity2>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.Entity1, c.Order });
    }
}
```

When I try to create a migration using

```
add-migration InitialMigration
```

I get the error;

```
The property 'Entity2.Entity1' is of type 'Entity1' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Comment: `Entity1` can't be part of the key.

Comment: I am pretty sure It is possible to make a foreign key into a primary key or part of a composite key. I just don't know how to specify it.

Comment: `Entity1` is not a foreign key. It's a reference. You need to add `Entity1Id` to the class.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks. I thought the EF saw it as a foreign key. I got the difference when I read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are trying to make `Entity1`'s primary key to be the part of `Entity2`'s composite primary key. So your `Entity2` should be as follows:

```
public class Entity2
{
    public string Entity1Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Entity2>()
        .HasKey(c => new { c.Entity1Id, c.Order });
}
```